# Preserve microphone settings while connecting Bluetooth headset

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones, microphone

When I'm connecting Bluetooth headset with microphone, OS X automatically selects new output and input devices (headsets microphone).

Is there any way to keep behavior of automatic output device selection while disabling switching over to the new input device (headset microphone)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would also like to do this as well. On Windows, I am able to go into the sound devices list and "Disable" a specific output devices which effectively prevents the OS from ever switching to it. I wish there was a way to "Disable" an input devices on Mac OS so that the OS never uses it. Does anyone know of a way to do this, perhaps via the terminal?